# Having different click areas on sidenav

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap and in that I am using side nav to serve collapsible list on the left side of the page. Below is my code.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li>
       <a class="active" href="#" onclick="loadelementsonpage(); return false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#licomp1">
          <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-v"></i>Parent1
       </a>
       <ul id="licomp1" class="collapse">
         <li><a href="#" onclick="loadelements1();">Child1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="loadelements2();">Child2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="loadelements3();">Child3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Instead of fixed `<i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-v"></i>` I want to use toggle plus and minus. As it is shown in code, I am calling one function when parent1 is clicked. But when I try to expand the ul, the function `loadelementsonpage()` is called everytime. So, I want list to collapse only when that toggle image is clicked. In the same way I want to call `loadelementsonpage()` only when the outer area of that toggle image is clicked. I changed this data-toggle and data-target to i class, but the problem is the function is still getting called and if I move the i class out of a tag, the style is messed up.

So can someone please shed some light on how to have different click areas on the parent li? One is for collapse and another is for calling function to load right side content page.

**P.S:**  Trying to implement this http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/modern-jquery-accordion-menu kind of side nav list where + or - should be clickable for only expanding and collapsing. Please click on build online in that link to see the side nav. Other area(apart from + and - icons) should act as link href to load the page.

Comment: This will be help full to you http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/

Comment: I like this sort of effect. Pretty straightforward too, and doesn't require JavaScript. http://jsfiddle.net/cLnn9ynf/3/

Comment: @SecondRikudo Hi, sorry, I tried my best to put in detail. Once again to be short, I have been trying to expand and collapse list only when button is clicked. Where as other area should be clickable for doing another thing(e.g., calling a javascript function). Please check the link which mentioned in question.

Comment: @rick you use jQuery in your project, right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yeah, I use JQuery, Bootstrap and even I am using [this theme](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/) for sidenav. But it combines both expansion and a on the same click. Where as I want to expand/collapse only on clicking of a button on the li and other area for other operation.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Hey, I think you have got my question wrong. Please look at my above comment.

Comment: Is this what you expect http://jsfiddle.net/f8z18kv3/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the data-toggle attribute to the anchor, give it to the icon element so that toggle works only for the icon. You can use the classes [here for plus and minus](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) and toggle between the classes `glyphicon-plus` and `glyphicon-minus`

```
<a class="active" href="#">
   <span data-toggle="collapse"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-target="#licomp1"></span>Parent1
</a>

$('.side-nav a span').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
});
```

Now on click of the anchor you can check if the element is `A` and if true then only call the custom function `loadelementsonpage`.

```
$('.side-nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.tagName);
    if (e.target.tagName == "A") {
        loadelementsonpage();
        return true;
    }
})

function loadelementsonpage() {
    alert('Load elements on page');
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/59g6zves/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the loadelementsonpage() is getting called for even children elements in your jsfiddle, because I have separate functions to call for each of them. How to avoid this?

Comment: Aah, I didn't check that. Can you give a class say `parent` to the parent anchor? If yes then you can change the condition to check if  `e.target` has the class `parent`. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/59g6zves/3/)

Comment: I did that already, thanks. One last question, how to go to particular child automatically and select. Say I want to show child2 to user and call loadelements2(). So, how to expand parent1 automatically and highlight child2?

Comment: You can use methods `.collapse('show')` to expand automatically and  on shown[`shown.bs.collapse`] event call the child's function. Click on expand button in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/59g6zves/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I added this too $('.side-nav a span').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus'); to change the icon in the expand function. I am gonna give bounty and would be able to do only after 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

***[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/lesihi/2/)***

Remove the inline JS you have in your HTML:

```
   <a class="active" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#licomp1">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-v"></i>Parent1
   </a>
```

And simply add this to your jQuery:

```
function loadelementsonpage(){
  alert("LOADED ELEMENTS! YIIHA"); // Or whatever goes here
}

$(".side-nav").on("click", "a[data-target]", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default Browser anchor-click behavior
  if( !$(e.target).hasClass("fa") ){ // If the clicked el. target was not `.fa`
    // means it was the parent `a` to get the click event.  Therefore...
    e.stopPropagation();         // prevent the click to propagate
                                 // to underneath layers triggering stuff and...
    return loadelementsonpage(); // execute (return) our desired function.
  }
});
```

<sup>(Make sure you have it in document.ready function)</sup>

What the above does

Comment: It worked except that I don't want to show the down arrow, instead I want to show the + and - icons when collapsed and expanded. Also, if you don't mind, could you pleas explain your answer, because I want to learn the answer, not just treat it as serving the purpose and +1.

Comment: @rick dohh sorry for not adding some code-comments. I usually do it.  (P.S. I don't know how to put the - and + icons but I think that's a Bootstrap thing) I used the *down arrow* right in HTML (in the demo link) just to test the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Proof of concept:

```js
function loadelementsonpage(target) {
  // example stuff
  $(target).toggle();
}

$(".side-nav").on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default Browser anchor-click behavior

  var icon = $(event.target).find('.collapseIcon');

  if (icon.text() === '+') {
    icon.text('-');
  } else {
    icon.text('+');
  }
  
  loadelementsonpage(event.target.getAttribute('data-target'));

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
  <li>
    <a class="active" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#licomp1">
      <span class="collapseIcon">-</span> Parent1
    </a>
    <ul id="licomp1" class="collapse">
      <li><a href="#">Child1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Child2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Child3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```